# Is there any elemental molecule which does not react well with anything but oxygen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecules, reactivity, elements

For example, phosphor reacts with oxygen but it also easily reacts with many halogens, metals, etc.

Is there any elemental molecule that doesn't react well with almost anything but oxygen?

Comment: No, there isn't. Asking similar question about fluorine would make more sense.